# real and imaginary part in $\sin z$ where z is complex

Tags: complex-numbers

I wanted to know, how can I determine the real and imaginary part in

> $\sin z$ where $z \in \Bbb{C}$?

Well, this is a part of a series of questions comprising the same in

> $\log z$ and $\tan^{-1} z$

I was able to solve this but no idea on how to solve for $\sin z$.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $z=x+iy, \sin(x+iy)=\sin x\cos (iy)+\cos x\sin(iy)=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y$  using the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions) between Hyperbolic & Trigonometric ratios

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$\sin z= \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\right)\\
e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Use the Euler formula for $\sin(z)$. Be sure to take care and define $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

We know that $$\sin  z= \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

From this definition we can get the real and imaginary parts.